# Correct way to inject dependency through property

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I was writing some code and I was told I have a potential bug in it. Our architect explained why, but I still don't see it. To me it looks like it is doing the same job even after his correction. Anybody can explain to me what was originaly wrong?

How it should look like according to our architect:

```
    private IIzuProxyService _izuProxyService = null;

    private IIzuProxyService IzuProxyService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_izuProxyService == null)
                _izuProxyService = new IzuProxyService();
            return _izuProxyService;
        }
    }
```

How It originaly looked:

```
    private IIzuProxyService _izuProxyService = null;

    private IIzuProxyService IzuProxyService
    {
        get
        {
            if (_izuProxyService == null)
                return new IzuProxyService();
            return _izuProxyService;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The original will always return a new instance. Note that there is no injection going on here.

Comment: In these kinds of situations, the debugger is your friend. Put a breakpoint on the `return new` line in the old code. Run it (such that it calls the getter twice). See what happens. Then change to the new code and do the same thing. You'll spot the bug right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never assigns to the `_izuProxyService` field.

This means that whenever the `IzuProxyService` property is accessed, `_izuProxyService` *always* `null`. Therefore it will *always* instantiate a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

The local field is never assigned a value and will remain null since the property getter returns a new instance each time without assigning a value to the local field.

A work around could be to use [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8) to manage the lazy loading of the desired field.

> Provides support for lazy initialization.

```
private Lazy<IIzuProxyService> _izuProxyService = new Lazy<IIzuProxyService>(() => new IzuProxyService() );

private IIzuProxyService IzuProxyService {
    get {
        return _izuProxyService.Value;
    }
}
```

The `Lazy<T>` replaces

```
if (_izuProxyService == null)
    _izuProxyService = new IzuProxyService();
return _izuProxyService;
```